# I want to generate numbers $1$ to $10$ with uniform probability distribution. Will this work?

Tags: probability-distributions, noise

I want to generate numbers $1$ to $10$ with uniform probability distribution.  So I write  the numbers $1$ to $10$ in the natural order.  I keep writing the next $10$ number block by permuting the first $10$ numbers.  Will this long string can be considered random with uniform distribution?  Is there a problem?

Comment: One issue is in truly randomly generated numbers, there are will be cases where consecutive numbers will be same. Also, what you are doing will be a fixed pattern after some number of cycles.

Comment: Not a good way. This choice could give very misleading answers for many simulations based on them.

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely not.  The resulting distribution of numbers will not be random, in the sense that successive observations will fail to be independent and identically distributed:  if $X_i$ is the value of the $i^{\rm th}$ observation, then suppose we observed $${\boldsymbol X}_{1:19} = (X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_{19}) = (3, 5, 7, 10, 4, 6, 2, 1, 8, 9, 4, 7, 2, 1, 9, 8, 6, 10, 3).$$  Then $$\Pr[X_{20} = 5 \mid {\boldsymbol X}_{1:19}] = 1.$$  Moreover, you cannot even have $$X_1 = X_2 = 1,$$ which is possible if in fact the $X_i$'s are all independent and identically distributed discrete uniform random variables on $\{1, \ldots, 10\}$.

Comment: The first point is wonderful.  In the permutation, there is randomness in the sense that you are not able to predict the next numebr.  In your example the probability is 1.  Even if one outcome is predictable, will the sequence become non-random?

Answer (score 2):

The distribution you will get will be far from uniformly distributed. For example, if I take 5 numbers between $1$ and $10$, there is a $0.001\%$ chance that all $5$ numbers will equal $3$. In your case, the probability is $0$. On the other hand, there will be exactly $100$ numbers that equal $5$ in the first $1000$ numbers you produce, while, if taking the truly random numbers, the probability of this happening is fairly low (something like $4.2\%$ if I am not mistaken).

---

So, where is the problem?

Your chain of numbers will be a chain of $10$ intertwined uniformly distributed variables, meaning that if you take your first, eleventh, twenty-first... number, the resulting requence will indeed be a sampling of a uniformly distributed random variable.

Comment: If it is truly uniform distribution, when I take 1000 numbers I am supposed to get hundred 1s, hundred 2s, hundred 3s and so on which is desirable.  Why should the probability be 4.2%?  Sorry, if I am missing some thing.

Comment: If I throw a $6$ sided die $10$ times, do you agree that that will produce a uniform distributions of numbers $1,2,3,4,5,6$?

Comment: No.  That is why I am saying that I permute them.  I keep permuting  and restrict the same numbers to occur equal number of times when I take a large number of observations so that they are uniformly distributed.

Comment: @user46468 Then you, unfortunatelly, have a false idea of what a uniform probability distribution is. I suggest you read the article on uniform probability distributions on wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_distribution_(discrete)

Comment: By the way: A die roll is a perfect example of a uniform distribution. In a uniform distribution, each number is selected randomly from the set of possible numbers, so the first number is one of the numbers $1,2,3,4,5,6$, and so is the second, *regardless* of what the first number is.